# VMware Fusion 3.1 - Slow Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, vmware, vmware-fusion

I'm working on a new Windows Phone 7 project. Unfortunately, I have only access to a VMware Fusion instance of Windows, from where I run Visual Studio and the Phone Emulator.

My problem is that the phone emulator takes ages (well, seconds) just to show up for example the keyboard for user input (when selecting a TextBox).

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878307/windows-phone-7-emulator-on-a-vm) that the problem comes from running a VM inside a VM.

My question is, if there is a trick which helps me to accelerate this somehow?

Thank you very much.

Cheers

EDIT:
Host machine: C2D 2.53Ghz, 4GB DDR3 RAM, SF-1200 SSD

Comment: I suspect that the solution may come down to the resources you have assigned to the VM. Can you add details about the host machine and the memory, processors, etc. that you have assigned to the VM to your question.

Comment: I tried a few configurations, e.g. 1-2 CPU Cores, 2-3GB RAM etc. - but that didn't make a difference. Developing with Visual Studio works great, the problem only occurs when loading up the WP7 VM (Taskmanager shows me 100% CPU usage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to say it, but the best solution is probably "don't run the emulator on a virtual machine".  The emulator is only officially supported on a real physical machine.

Other than that, you will need to max out the resources available to the VM.

You're lucky you haven't ripped a hole in the fabric of spacetime by running an emulator on an emulator :)

See also: [Windows Phone 7 emulator on a VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878307/windows-phone-7-emulator-), or [Windows Mobile 7 Emulator Kills VMware](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/5c67cd6f-a221-4975-8479-8904a52c8366)