# Is Windows Phone 7 programming available on Mac OS X based computers?

Tags: macos, windows-phone-7

I'm eager to start developing for WP7, but restarting my Mac to boot Windows seems pretty annoying. Is there any usable ways of WP7 development on Mac **except virtual machines**?

Thanks in regards.

Comment: not running in a vm is terrible.  That just means I won't develop for it, i guess this is similar to how apple started out, only dev on osx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VM is not an option, the Windows Phone emulator will not run from within a VM ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878307/windows-phone-7-emulator-on-a-vm) an answer to an earlier SO question stating the reasons for that). The only option is to shutdown and boot Windows, however annoying that may be.

Answer (score 3):

To develop WP7 using IDE such as Visual Studio .NET you have to work on Windows. So the only way is too install virtualisation such as VMWare Fusion or Parallel for MAC.

Hope this helps.

DCA

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the open source .Net implementation Mono, but in order to actually test your applications and install them onto a WP7 device, you need Zune and that is not available on OS X.

The best option would be a VM to run Windows and Visual Studio.

Comment: VM is not an option either, the Windows Phone emulator will not run from within a VM. The only option is to shutdown and boot Windows, however annoying that may be.

Comment: @Prætorian so you also can't directly debug with a WP device via VM? Because I don't really need the emulator, just being able to upload my binaries to the device.

Comment: @TomSchoffelen Don't know, never tried it. But the limitation I mentioned only applies to the emulator, so you might be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 is now available on Mac. I haven't play with it yet, but it should at least support developing mobile apps using Xamarin. Another good news is that there is free VS version (community edition):

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/